# Connecting to IdentityServer4 / ASP.NET Core Identity from another application

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have created an IdentityServer 4 project with ASP.NET Core Identity as the user store.

I want to use ID4/ASP.NET as a service and I want to call this service from another web application which isn't .NET core and valid the username and password supplied is correct.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to connect non-ASP.NET Core clients to Identity Server 4.

But in order to give you a more detailed answear we need information about what clients you want to connect towards IDSvr4.

I have connected the following clients to IDSvr4:

- ASP.NET Core
- ASP.NET MVC
- ASP.NET Webforms

In order to connect the last two clients you need to:

1. Compile them using minimum .NET Framework 4.5.
2. Reference and implement a Katana (OWIN) pipeline.
3. Define cookie middleware.
4. Define OpenID Connect middleware.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply.  It would be ASP.NET Webforms

Comment: Ok, that's possible to do by completing the above 4 steps.

Comment: Can you just connect to the ASP.NET Identity database from your ASP.NET Webforms and use the Identity EF functions to check passwords etc and then use the full ID4 OAuth implementation for the mobile and API security

Comment: You need to read the documentation and view all github repos of IDSvr3. The idea is to let IDSvr be responsible of authentication and make your clidnts rely on that authentication. But authorization is something which still should/could be handled in the clients.